# JavaScript Closure Scope with two functions

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I'm struggling with closure scope in a JavaScrit function. The function below should create three swatches with different images (which works), then when these are clicked, should switch the stylesheet.

The problem is that the same object is passed to the `switchTheme` function even though stepping through shows the `theme` variable in the first function does change.

```
var switcherConfig = {
    themes: 
        {
            'Orangeness': {
                folder: 'ui-lightness'
            },
            'Red Matter': {
                folder: 'blitzer'
            },
            'Flubber': {
                folder: 'south-street'
            }
        }
}
function createThemeSwitcher(placeholderSelector) {
    for (var themeName in switcherConfig.themes) {
        var theme = switcherConfig.themes[themeName];
        var anchor = $('<a/>')
            //.text(theme.title)
            .attr('title', theme.title)
            .attr('href', '#')
            .on('click', function () { switchTheme(theme); })
            // append to DOM etc
    }
}
function switchTheme(theme) {
    var themeDirectory = switcherConfig.baseDirectory + '/' + theme.folder + '/';
    // 'theme' variable is always the last in my 'themes' config object
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value used by `switchTheme(theme)` will be the state that `theme` is in when the function is called, the value is not bound at the moment you create that anonymous callback. Use a closure to bind that particular value:

```
.on('click', (function (t) {
    return function () { switchTheme(t); };
})(theme))
```

Comment: That piece of code makes an anonymous function which takes a value `t` and returns a function that calls `switchTheme` with that value. You're then immediately calling that anonymous function, passing it the current value of `theme`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I am quite confused, but this looks correct. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
var theme = switcherConfig.themes[themeName];
```

to click function

```
function createThemeSwitcher(placeholderSelector) {
    for (var themeName in switcherConfig.themes) {

        var anchor = $('<a/>')
            //.text(theme.title)
            .attr('title', theme.title)
            .attr('href', '#')
            .on('click', function () { 
                         var theme = switcherConfig.themes[themeName];
                         switchTheme(theme); 
            })
            // append to DOM etc
    }
}
```

Comment: the theme.title will fail while setting attribute title

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making closure you can use `.data` like below (just an alternative):

```
var switcherConfig = {
    themes: 
        {
            'Orangeness': {
                title:"Orangeness",
                folder: 'ui-lightness'
            },
            'Red Matter': {
                                title:'Red Matter',
                folder: 'blitzer'
            },
            'Flubber': {
                title:'Flubber',
                folder: 'south-street'
            }
        }
}
function createThemeSwitcher(placeholderSelector) {
    for (var themeName in switcherConfig.themes) {
        var theme = switcherConfig.themes[themeName];
        var anchor = $('<a/>')
            .data("theme",theme)
            .attr('title', theme.title)
            .attr('href', '#')
            .html(theme.title)
            .on('click', function () { switchTheme($(this).data("theme")); })
            $("body").append(anchor);
    }
}
function switchTheme(theme) {
    alert(theme.title)
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZmjD/1/)